# Insert a counter in a *animate* image

Tags: animate

I'm learning the basics of the animate package.
In a simple image I want to insert a counter that represents the time.
Here there is the code I've used.

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}
   \usepackage[italian]{babel}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usepackage[controls]{animate} 
    %=====================
    \begin{document}
    %=====================

   \begin{figure}

\begin{animateinline}
   [
        loop,
        controls,
        begin={
                      \begin{tikzpicture}
                      \useasboundingbox (-3,-3) rectangle (10, 5);
                   },
       end={\end{tikzpicture}}
   ]{10}
 \multiframe {40}{n=0+0.05}  % andata
{ 
\draw[very thick](-2,0) -- (-1,0); %linee
\draw[very thick](-2,2) -- (-1,2);
%
\draw[->,very thick](0,0) -- (9,0); %assi
  \draw[->,very thick](0,-2) -- (0,4);
  \filldraw [red] (-1.5,0+\n) circle (1pt) ;                %fotone
\draw[dashed,red] (-1.5,0+\n)--(0+\n,0+\n); %proiezione
 \draw [thick,red] (0,0)--(0+\n,0+\n); %grafico
%%counter
 \node [thick, black] at (1,-1){$t=$};
 \node [thick, black] at (2,-1){$\n$};
}
%
 \multiframe {40}{n=0+0.05}     %ritorno
{ 
\draw[very thick](-2,0) -- (-1,0); %linee
\draw[very thick](-2,2) -- (-1,2);
%
\draw[->,very thick](0,0) -- (9,0); %assi
  \draw[->,very thick](0,-2) -- (0,4);
  \draw [red] (0,0)--(2,2);
   \filldraw [blue] (-1.5,2-\n) circle (1pt) ;                  %fotone
\draw[dashed,blue] (-1.5,2-\n)--(2+\n,2-\n); %proiezione
 \draw [thick,blue] (2,2)--(2+\n,2-\n); % grafico
}

\end{animateinline}
%
\end{figure}
%======================
\end{document}
%======================
```

With this solution the digits of the number that represents the time change all at any frame, giving a fastidious effect of blink that it is also difficult to read.
So my question is: there is some way to have a counter that change only the changing digit, as in a digital timer?

Comment: Please edit your post and add a working document, not just the fragments

Comment: I've added all the code. But it seems not possible to add the pdf image that is generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is more about formatting numbers. The `siunitx` package is perfectly suited for this purpose as it allows rounding numbers to significant decimal places and correctly typesetting physical units.

E. g. a number with unit:

```
$t=\SI[round-mode=places,round-precision=2]{123.4567}{\second}$
```

should appear as "*t* = 123.46 s" on paper.

Or without unit:

```
$t=\num[round-mode=places,round-precision=2]{123.4567}$
```

---

One `animate`-related recommendation concerning the given code is to *always* separate two subsequent `\multiframe` blocks with a `\newframe` (as stated somewhere in the `animate` documentation).

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[controls]{animate} 
\usepackage{siunitx}

%=====================
\begin{document}
%=====================

\begin{figure}

\begin{animateinline}
[
  loop,
  begin={
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \useasboundingbox (-3,-3) rectangle (10, 5);
  },
  end={\end{tikzpicture}}
]{10}
  \multiframe {40}{n=0+0.05}  % andata
  { 
    \draw[very thick](-2,0) -- (-1,0); %linee
    \draw[very thick](-2,2) -- (-1,2);
    %
    \draw[->,very thick](0,0) -- (9,0); %assi
      \draw[->,very thick](0,-2) -- (0,4);
      \filldraw [red] (-1.5,0+\n) circle (1pt) ;                %fotone
    \draw[dashed,red] (-1.5,0+\n)--(0+\n,0+\n); %proiezione
     \draw [thick,red] (0,0)--(0+\n,0+\n); %grafico
    %counter
    \node [thick, black] at (1,-1){$t=\SI[round-mode=places,round-precision=2]{\n}{\second}$};
  }
  \newframe% required between two \multiframe blocks
  \multiframe {40}{n=0+0.05, nTime=2+0.05}     %ritorno
  { 
    \draw[very thick](-2,0) -- (-1,0); %linee
    \draw[very thick](-2,2) -- (-1,2);
    %
    \draw[->,very thick](0,0) -- (9,0); %assi
    \draw[->,very thick](0,-2) -- (0,4);
    \draw [red] (0,0)--(2,2);
    \filldraw [blue] (-1.5,2-\n) circle (1pt) ;                  %fotone
    \draw[dashed,blue] (-1.5,2-\n)--(2+\n,2-\n); %proiezione
    \draw [thick,blue] (2,2)--(2+\n,2-\n); % grafico
    %counter
    \node [thick, black] at (1,-1){$t=\SI[round-mode=places,round-precision=2]{\nTime}{\second}$};
  }

\end{animateinline}
%
\caption{\dots}
\end{figure}
%======================
\end{document}
%======================
```